# .Net DriveInfo() with UNC paths?

Tags: .net, unc, driveinfo

Good morning,

is there a way to get a DriveInfo instance for UNC paths (e.g. "\fors343a.ww123.somedomain.net\folder\1\") because for example...

```
var driveInfo = new System.IO.DriveInfo(drive);
```

... throws an ArgumentException ("Object must be a root directory (\"C:\\") or a drive letter (\"C\").") when using that UNC path above.

What would I use in order to retrieve information about that or e.g. how would I check whether a given folder resides on a local drive or an unc path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Remarks section for the `DriveInfo` constructor says:

> The drive name must be either an
>   uppercase or lowercase letter from 'a'
>   to 'z'. You cannot use this method to
>   obtain information on drive names that
>   are nullNothingnullptra null reference
>   (Nothing in Visual Basic) or use UNC
>   (\server\share) paths.

I was able to make it work by mapping a network drive in Windows Explorer.  That is, I mapped "\server\share" to drive Z, and then `DriveInfo("Z:\\");` gave me what I expected.

Unfortunately, there's no simple way to map a network drive from C#.  You'll either have to execute an external command (i.e. "net use z: \server\share"), or call the Windows [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413(VS.85).aspx) API function to do it.  Either way you go, you'll need to remove the drive mapping when you're done.

Comment: really silly why c# doesn't have an easy method for unc paths. What if someone else maps something to that drive letter later then program would fail. There must be a reliable way of just using unc path alone

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, the following works great in C# (at least to get the sizes, which is what is most commonly needed):

```
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName, out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable, out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes, out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Here is some sample code (this hasn't actually been compiled in this form, but is bits and pieces from working code scattered across multiple files):

```
/// <summary>
/// A compilation of the properties of folders and files in a file system.
/// </summary>
public struct FileSystemProperties
{
    private FileSystemProperties(long? totalBytes, long? freeBytes, long? availableBytes)
        : this()
    {
        TotalBytes = totalBytes;
        FreeBytes = freeBytes;
        AvailableBytes = availableBytes;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the total number of bytes on the drive.
    /// </summary>
    public long? TotalBytes { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of bytes free on the drive.
    /// </summary>
    public long? FreeBytes { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of bytes available on the drive (counts disk quotas).
    /// </summary>
    public long? AvailableBytes { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the properties for this file system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="volumeIdentifier">The path whose volume properties are to be queried.</param>
    /// <param name="cancel">An optional <see cref="CancellationToken"/> that can be used to cancel the operation.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="FileSystemProperties"/> containing the properties for the specified file system.</returns>
    public static FileSystemProperties GetProperties(string volumeIdentifier)
    {
        ulong available;
        ulong total;
        ulong free;
        if (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(volumeIdentifier, out available, out total, out free))
        {
            return new FileSystemProperties((long)total, (long)free, (long)available);
        }
        return new FileSystemProperties(null, null, null);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Asynchronously gets the properties for this file system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="volumeIdentifier">The path whose volume properties are to be queried.</param>
    /// <param name="cancel">An optional <see cref="CancellationToken"/> that can be used to cancel the operation.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> containing the <see cref="FileSystemProperties"/> for this entry.</returns>
    public static async Task<FileSystemProperties> GetPropertiesAsync(string volumeIdentifier, CancellationToken cancel = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ulong available;
            ulong total;
            ulong free;
            if (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(volumeIdentifier, out available, out total, out free))
            {
                return new FileSystemProperties((long)total, (long)free, (long)available);
            }
            return new FileSystemProperties(null, null, null);
        }, cancel);
    }
}
```

Don't try to use this on Linux or Mac--it would have to be rewritten for those (and I'd be interested to see that).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but neither answer is the simplest answer: Read the registry & get the mapped drives + UNC paths.

The registry path is HKCU\Network. Each key is the mapped drive letter & the RemotePath value is the UNC path for the drive mapping.

Simple registry read.