# How to get Network drive size in C# (without "map drive")

Tags: c#

I need to get the free space of a Network drive, without "map drive"

```
DriveInfo drvInfo = new DriveInfo("\\NetworkDrive");
```

I try to do this but it does not work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676734/net-driveinfo-with-unc-paths - DriveInfo doesn't work with UNC paths (it even specifies that in the help).  Try @Mitch's suggstion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you will need to call `GetDiskFreeSpace` (Win32 API) via [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getdiskfreespace) to get the disk free space of a UNC network drive.

e.g.

[C# GetDiskFreeSpace UNC](http://www.sergey.co.uk/ShowThread.aspx?ID=4563&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot but can You explain more Please

Comment: @Hiyasat please see the linked to example

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI to connect to the remote computer and display the free space for each drive.

An example can be found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/418820-space-available-remote-computer)