Detect if remote computer's hard drive is full when trying to copy a file to it. System.IO IOException
At my company, we have a chronic problem with tiny SSD's filling. Sometimes the SSD (HD) is so full that a 2KB file won't fit on it when copied to it from across the network. System.IO will throw an error:

IOExeption: There is not enough space on the disk

I want to catch the full HD IOException and attempt to remotely delete C:\Windows\Temp directory to open HD space for further disk cleanup maintenance.
I wrote the following to catch the full HD IOException; I cannot test for success as I do not have a client with a full HD to test against.
Will the below code work?
catch (IOException ioEX) when (ioEX.Message == "There is not enough space on the disk.")
{
    try
    {
        string remoteWindowsTemp = @"\\" + computerName + @"\C$\Windows\Temp";

        // Attempt to clear off HD space directly from local computer
        Directory.Delete(remoteWindowsTemp, true);
    }
    catch 
    {  
        // ...Other IO conditions I have written that I know work... }
    }
}



I don't think the C$ share is available across network (although I have never tried). You should of course test that. Also test if you can indeed access the Tempfolder.

Yup, there is logic around this script that works just fine with C$ share... Do it all the time.

May be you can check with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676734/net-driveinfo-with-unc-paths#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20there%27s%20no%20simple%20way%20to%20map%20a,to%20remove%20the%20drive%20mapping%20when%20you%27re%20done.

Good suggestion, but would have to run a Process object to launch command prompt net use command to map a drive to check the size. The above process only bombs when the target HD is full and runs just fine every other time. A long, round-about solution for 1% failure... Would rather just catch and handle when exception is caught. But good suggestions coming in... Keep 'em coming!

Well, I think the real problem here is that the disk is full in first case, that should never happen. May be you should implement a network wide solution, where you periodically runs CleanMgr  on all computers.

@PoulBak Correct, and we do have a network wide solution.... BUT, there is a legal hold requirement that "blocks" the clean-up. There are many questions about storing legally sensitive data on a volatile HD... Don't get me started... But essentially your statement is true, and does exist... FYI

You can PInvoke the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx function from the kernel, and use it for a network location:
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
  string lpDirectoryName, 
  out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable, // free space available to the current user - could be smaller than the actual disk free space
  out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes, // used space
  out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes); // free space in the whole disk

bool HasEnoughSpace(string srcFile, string destPath) {
  var fileBytes = (ulong)(new FileInfo(srcFile).Length);
  GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(destPath, out var availableBytes, out _, out _);

  return fileBytes <= availableBytes;
}

if (!HasEnoughSpace(@"C:\MyFile.txt", @"\\127.0.0.1\C$")) {
  // Clear some space
}



-or-
If you do go the route of catching the Exception, matching some magic string is usually smelly, as it is subject to Locale, and isn't guaranteed to not change on an OS update. It's better to match by error code. And in this particular case, the error was ERROR_DISK_FULL (0x70).
In an IOException, the system error code is attached to its HResult:
const int ERROR_DISK_FULL = 0x70;

try {

} catch (IOException ex) when (ex.HResult == ERROR_DISK_FULL) {
  // Clear some space
}


Your second block is what I am looking for. Since the absolute full hard drive exception only comes through 1% of the time on a truly full HD, I don't want to query the HD every time for 1% of this expected and imminent error. Thanks a ton!

I also found this for more granularity on handling...
How to check if IOException is Not-Enough-Disk-Space-Exception type?

@ScyWatcher There's also ERROR_FILE_TOO_LARGE to be safe, maybe?

Thanks for the foresight. I like how your mind anticipates potential future issues! For my scenario, this should not be an issue since I only deliver ~2Mb files and am deleting gigs. You've reminded me of those error codes! I've added your link to MS error codes to my bookmarks!
